# How to attach mysql database when creating a setup?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using `vb.net` and `xampp` for creating my project. I want to attach the database on my setup file so that i wont have to install `xampp` on other computer just to make it work. Do i have to install database server?

Answer (score 0):

> Do i have to install database server?

Only on the machine where MySQL will run, not on every machine that runs your vb.net application. Shared data residing in a shared MySQL database is the point of using database technology.

You will need to provide a connection string to every user or every machine that runs your vb.net application. That connection string must specify these items of information

- the hostname or ip address of the machine running MySQL
- the name of the database on MySQL used for your application
- the username of the user account *on MySQL* with access to the database
- the password for the user account.

Your connection string will look something like this:

```
 Server=MySQLHost;Database=myDataBase;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

For example, if your server is on 192.168.1.220, the database name is `saldieApp`, the MySQL username is `ourMySQL`, and the shared password is `dontTellMom`, your connection string is

```
 Server=192.168.1.220;Database=saldieApp;Uid=ourMySQL;Pwd=dontTellMom;
```

Your vb.net program will do something like this to connect to MySQL.

```
Dim conn as MySQLConnection
conn = New MySqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=MySQLHost;Database=myDataBase;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
conn.Open()
```

The trick for installing a company-wide application using a shared database is to distribute the appropriate connection string to each user.  You can put that connection string in your setup file. Or you can do something more secure that doesn't require you to store the password in your setup file.